# Appendix name in the headers and in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr, appendices

My problem is quite simple : I want to have a TOC like that :

> Chapitre 1 - Some chapter title
>
> Annexe A - Some appendix title

but I get :

> Chapitre 1 - Some chapter title
>
> Chapitre A - Some appendix title

In fact I redefined the table of contents (code below)

Same problem with the headers : I want :

> Annexe A - Some appendix title

not

> Chapitre A - Some appendix title

Here is a MWE to show you the problem :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% Ecrire en français
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace} % Pour les espaces automatiques

% En têtes
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~- ~#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername~\thechapter~-~ #1}{}}

\fancypagestyle{main}{
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 pt}

}


% Part name in TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{part}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{Partie \Roman{part} --\hspace{-.4cm}}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapitre\ }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{\hfill--\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{3.2cm}
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}
%\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %Si on veut mettre des pointillés
%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\newcommand\Bpart[1]{\part{\texorpdfstring{}{}#1}}
\newcommand\Bchapter[1]{\chapter{\texorpdfstring{}{Chapitre \arabic{chapter} -- }#1}}

% Nouvelles commandes
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{main}

\chapter{Some plain stuff}

\appendix 

\chapter{Some appendix stuff}

\chapter{Some other}
\end{document}
```

A clever thing would be to redefine `\chaptername` when `\appendix` came in the code, but I didn't succeed.

If someone knows how to fix this please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: `\@chapapp` normally does this it expand to `\chaptername` or `\appendixname`

Comment: I don't know this command, but I will search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

1. for headers you need to set

---

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\@chapapp~\thechapter~-~ #1}{}}
\makeatother
```

---

2. For toc you need to set

---

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\@chapapp\ }
\makeatother
```

and add after `\appendix`

```
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{\@chapapp\ }}
\makeatother
```

**Note** you can simply do it with `\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\ }`
and then add after `\appendix`: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{\appendixname\ }}`
to avoid using `\makeatletter--\makeatother`

---

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% Ecrire en français
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace} % Pour les espaces automatiques

% En têtes
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~- ~#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\@chapapp~\thechapter~-~ #1}{}}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{main}{
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 pt}

}


% Part name in TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{part}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{Partie \Roman{part} --\hspace{-.4cm}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\@chapapp\ }
\makeatother
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{\hfill--\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{3.2cm}
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}
%\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %Si on veut mettre des pointillés
%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\newcommand\Bpart[1]{\part{\texorpdfstring{}{}#1}}
\newcommand\Bchapter[1]{\chapter{\texorpdfstring{}{Chapitre \arabic{chapter} -- }#1}}

% Nouvelles commandes
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}


\begin{document}



\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{main}

\chapter{Some plain stuff}

\appendix \makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{\@chapapp\ }}
\makeatother

\chapter{Some appendix stuff}

\chapter{Some other}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly !